# How to document properties of properties of services?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, documentation, jsdoc, ngdoc

Given this code:

```
var zomg = angular.module('zomg', []);

/**
 * @ngdoc object
 * @name zomg.Foo
 * @description
 * # Foo
 */
zomg.factory('Foo', [function () {
  return {
    /**
     * @ngdoc object
     * @name zomg.Foo.bar
     * @propertyOf zomg.Foo
     * @description
     * A property of Foo
     */
    bar: {
      /**
       * @ngdoc object
       * @name zomg.Foo.bar.baz
       * @propertyOf zomg.Foo.bar
       * @description
       * A property of Foo.bar
       */
      baz: 100
    }
  };
}]);
```

I get this documentation:

[image]

That is, the `Foo.bar.baz` property doesn't show up in the documentation. It is parsed properly - since if I change `@propertyOf` from `zomg.Foo.bar` to something like `zomg.Foo.doesnotexist`, I get an error when compiling the documentation. But the results don't show up in the resulting HTML.

How should I document nested objects? The actual use case is that I have a service which contains `$resource`s, and I want to document the special methods on the `$resource`. I'd rather do it in a standard jsdoc way (`@ngdoc function` with `@methodOf` of the special function itself) rather than including it in the `@description` of the `$resource` in a non-standard way.